# problema con visualización de imagen de fondo en CSS

Tags: html, css

hola soy nuevo en este tema y estoy aprendiendo de manera autodidacta. La cuestión es que estoy tratando de hacer una pantalla de login y al momento de querer poner una imagen de fondo en css no me aparece el fondo. algún consejo? desde ya gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Transparent Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css">

  <body>
    <div class="login-box">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
      </div>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
      </div>

      <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">

    </div>





  </body>

</html>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(paisajepuente.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Podrías copiar tu código para facilitar la ayuda que podamos brindarte?

Comment: De momento, modifica tu estilo por este: background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/24HCs.png");

Comment: Tu código tal cual esta es funcional, la única razón válida para que no funcione es que la ruta de tu imagen esta errónea, ¿podrías indicarnos por favor las carpetas y donde se encuentra cada archivo?

Answer (score 4):

Siguiendo tu código, lo primero que debes hacer es cerrar tu etiqueta `<head>`, ya que tienes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Transparent Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css">

  <body>
    <div class="login-box">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
      </div>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
      </div>

      <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Y debería ser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Transparent Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css">
</head>

<body>
   .
   .
   .
</body>
</html>
```

- Luego, para añadir un fondo a tu página web, tienes que verificar dos cosas.

  1. Que tu Ruta `css` sea la correcta. Es decir, si tienes:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css">
```

Significa que tu archivo `.html` se encuentra en la misma ruta que tu archivo `.css`.

Si esto no es así, y tienes tu archivo `.css` en otra ruta (p.e en otra carpeta), se haria lo siguiente para poder acceder a ella:

[image: ruta]

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="carpeta/stylelogin.css">
```

Ahora, ya que verificamos que todo este correcto, podemos agregar un fondo a tu etiqueta `body` de la siguiente manera, utilizando [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp):

```css
body {
    background-image: url ('imagen.jpg');
    /* otras declaraciones */
}
```

2. La imagen solo aparecerá si la ruta a ella esta bien, es decir, si tienes la misma ruta del archivo `.css` no debería darte problema, pero si tienes la imagen en otro archivo, no aparecerá hasta poder acceder a ella.

Por ejemplo, si tu imagen se encuentra en una carpeta (y dicha carpeta en la misma ruta que el archivo css), seria de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body {
    background-image: url ('img/imagen.jpg');
    /* otras declaraciones */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ocupas solo para el login esa imagen, en el css crea la clase .login.body

```
.login.body{
   background: url("../images/paisajepuente.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
```

}
y en donde inicia el body de tu vista login, manda a llamar esa clase

```
<body class="login body">
```

asi no tendrias porque crear diferentes archivos css

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

Crearas una clase de Css que en este caso se llama fondo, luego la llamas en el desde a etiqueta body para que te tome todo el cuerpo de la pagina como fondo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Transparent Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css">

<style>
.fondo{
 position: relative; 

    url("https://via.placeholder.com/1200x700"); /*AQUI COLOCA BIEN LA RUTA DE TU IMAGEN*/

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%; 
height: 740px;/*aqui personaliza el tamaño*/

max-width: 100%;
 
}
</style>

</head>
  <body class="fondo">
    <div class="login-box">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
      </div>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
      </div>

      <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">

    </div>





  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Recuerda que responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, por favor lee [answer]